# What happens when using Jsoup.connect()? Why is it so slow?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm using the following line to load document

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.some.site.with.lotsof.images/")
        .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
        .maxBodySize(0)
        .timeout(600000).get();  // So Slow (~10 Seconds)
Elements lyricList = doc.getElementsByClass("some-class");
```

I need only the src of the images. So i need only the plain html text to be loaded.

Is the line slow because of loading images from the URL?

I mean does Jsoup.connect() wait for the whole page to be loaded along with the images?

Comment: Are you sure that your images are loaded from paths to resources like `<img src="/some/path/to/image.jpg"/>` and don't contain image data in HTML code itself like `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw....."/>`?

Comment: yeah i'm sure abt that. I've copied and seen the whole html during debug.

Answer (score 3):

instead of using `Jsoup` for fetching and parsing, try combining `OkHttp` for fetching and `Jsoup` for parsing

```
OkHttpClient okHttp = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://example.com").get().build();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(okHttp.newCall(request).execute().body().string());
```

it made a great difference in my case, here are the average results for a simple benchmark I ran:

> okHttp+Jsoup: 283ms
>
> Jsoup: 476ms

Answer (score 1):

`Jsoup` connection might become slow because of:

- your **internet connection speed** or
- **CPU usage** (Some other program is eating up memory!) or
- the **respond speed** of the web server you are accessing.

I've been scraping thousands of pages and the above three (**especially the third one**) have been the most likely problems to slow down `Jsoup.connect()`. In your case I believe it's the web server you are trying to connect to that is slowing down your connection because `Jsoup` does not wait for images to load, it gets you whatever the initial `html` response from the server is.